# Offline Voice search on ICS?

Tags: voice-command, offline

I have an Samsung Galaxy Exhilarate, with 4.0.4 operating system. Is there a way to get offline voice search for Ice Cream Sandwhich or below?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, offline voice recognition is only available for devices running Android 4.1 (Jelly Bean) and above - anything below that will not receive support. There is, however, another hidden requirement - your device must have a sufficient amount of RAM in order to be able to download the Offline Voice Recognition files from Google. My Incredible S is running 4.2.2 and with 572 MBs of RAM I do not see the option.

Should you receive an upgrade to 4.1+ (by root or other means), you may go to `Language and Input` in Settings and select `Download offline speech recognition` under `Voice Search`.