# Offline voice recognition not working

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, voice-recognition

When my phone is not connected to internet, voice search is showing "Can't reach Google at the moment" message and voice search is not working. It is working perfectly with internet connection.

The settings shows that it has English(UK) and English(US) as two downloaded languages for offline recognition. I have an android phone running JellyBean 4.2.2 in it. I think my OS version and RAM size (2 GB) supports voice recognition as mentioned in this [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/51014/34149).

Any idea how this can be solved?

Comment: You are talking about 'voice search'. It requires the internet to search the internet. How can it say something without searching the internet?

Comment: I think using voice search, we can search apps, contacts, etc, issue voice commands like "call somebody", "play music" ..

Comment: I know but voice search still requires the internet because 'call someone' can also be a google search.

Comment: But if you have internet connectivity and say "call 12345" voice search will start call 12345 instead of searching with google.

Comment: offline multilingual doesn't work: it only recognize a single language. (When 2 languages are added, it only recognize English (or the first one?))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Voice search works in offline mode in Android Lolipop. In previous version you can use offline voice recognition only for writing messages (after click microphone icon on Android on screen keyborad).

Also be sure that your Google application is up to date:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox

Answer (score 0):

select english(US) as default language, select this only uncheck all others,see if it works i tried and solved it

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: "Change primary language to match the offline language pack (if US then US, if UK then UK). The offline language packs are limited. Andriod should have language variants fall back to the generic instead of failing, but in this version it didn't."

https://wordpress.com/post/andioio.wordpress.com/26