# Google Voice Search requiring internet access even when offline speech recognition pack is installed

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, google, voice-recognition, offline

When installed, the Google app includes Voice Search.

In the settings for Voice Search, there is an option to install *Offline speech recognition* packs.

Despite doing this, Voice Search is still requiring internet access to perform speech recognition for simple tasks like writing messages or loading an app (both of which are **offline** tasks).

Although [this Android SE question is specific for Jelly Bean](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/100492/offline-voice-recognition-not-working), offline recognition should also be working in KitKat.

For Android KitKat, how do you fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out:

1. Go to Android Settings, and select the *Input* (sometimes called *Language and input*) page.
2. Within the *Input* page, enable *Google voice typing*.

Now offline speech recognition should work.